# Is it possible to create Non CMS Page

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, cms-pages, maintenance

Is it possible to create a non CMS page?

Basically, I want a static 'coming soon' page in front of my website in the run up to it's launch, but I can't find a way to do this in the backend. It this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show a coming soon page to your website visitors do the following;

1. Access your server through SSH or FTP and edit the .htaccess file by adding the line below (make sure you check to see if it already has one with "index.php" - comment it out if it does with ##) 
   DirectoryIndex index.html
2. Save the .htaccess file
3. create a new file and name it index.html
4. Edit it with your coming soon content and save.
5. Refresh your browser and you should see the new page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @RiccardoT you can prvent google from indexing the page by simply adding a meta tag on the header of the coming soon page like below;  
[code]<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
</head> [/code]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maintenance page.

Create an empty file name `maintenance.flag` on your Magento root and customize `errors/default/503.phtml` (change according to your current theme).

Comment: This is a bad idea from SEO standpoint.

Comment: Hi Ben, New2Magento was talking about a coming soon page, I think indexing a temporary page would be worst than asking Google to come here later.

Comment: I mean: with 503 you have the "Retry-After" header. With a 200 code Google will index your coming soon page. I'm not a SEO specialist and you are my Magento hero, so I can be wrong.

Comment: Can't set retry-after via native maintenance page. Semantically, the response should be 200.